# Rewrite URL to optimize for search engine

Tags: url, seo, url-rewriting

I want a URL on the form

```
mypage.com/ID/Some-random-text
```

to load its content from

```
mypage.com/loadstuff.php?id=ID
```

Can anyone show how this is done?

I have looked on different SEO optimization websites but not been able to figure out how to do this particular trick.

Comment: What do you mean? Is it not allowed to ask technical questions with the purpose of optimizing a website for search engines?

Comment: SEO and rewrite questions are not on-topic at this website. The belong at Webmasters.

Comment: I apologize, but I did not know that. I found the "SEO" tag in here and more than hundred related questions also under the tag "SEO", so I thought it would be okay to ask for help. I am sorry if anyone was annoyed by me going off-topic.

Comment: It's ok and no one is annoyed. It's a regular occurrence here and it makes sense why it happens. :)

Comment: I think it would help if we could vote for removing the SEO tag. I think many people use the tags as a guidance for proper topics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use apache httpd URL rewriting for this.

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)/.*$ /loadstuff.php?id=$1
```

Note this example is not tested. You can find out more here https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html

Other web servers likely have similar options.

Comment: Thank you. I used your link and the idea from your answer to get this rule working:
RewriteRule ^(.*)/.*$ loadstuff.php?id=$1